# View/Edit Sql Entry from another Sql Entry

Tags: php, sql

I have a question which might sound a bit confusing but i'll try my best to explain my problem.

I have 2 tables in my sql database: Table 1 is called Events, Table2 is called Results

The Events table contains entries about a past computer game match

```
eg. EventID   EventName  EventDate  Location 
      1       GG vs AU    04/08     Game room 1
```

The Results table contains nearly the same entries.. but with more detail for that single entry

```
eg.  EventID   MemberID       Score        Ranking 
       1         02        7(victory):5      1st
```

Basically, I will go into the "Events" php file, and I will see the entries.
When I press any of the entries in the same row, (eg. 1, GGvsAU, 04/08, Gameroom1), itll link me to the Results Table which will give me a bit more indepth information about that match.
from that example, the eventID is 1 so when I press any of the entries in the same row, itll link me to results.php?EventID=1

The Events php file is working perfectly so its all good.. but once I press the entry, it links me to the Results php file.

What I have trouble right now is with the Results php file. When I press the entry in Events.php, it links me to results.php?EventID=1, but it shows me all the entries inside the database.. I want only the info for EventID1..

Also, would it be possible to "HIDE" the EventID and the "MemberID from view based on my codes below?

Events.php

```
<?
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=clubresults', 'root', '12345678');
    #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

$query = $pdo->query('SELECT EventID, EventName, EventDate, Location from events');
$rowset = array();

if ($query) {
  while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // Build array of rows
    $rowset[] = $row;
  }    

  // Output header first
  $headrow = $rowset[0];
  print("<table border=\"1\">\n<tr>\n");
  // Use $rowset[0] to write the table heading
  foreach ($headrow as $col => $val) {
    printf("<th>%s</th>\n", $col);
  }
  print("</tr>");

  // Then output table rows.
  // Outer loop iterates over row
  foreach ($rowset as $row) {
     print("<tr>");
     // Inner loop iterates over columns using $col => $val
     foreach ($row as $col => $val) {
        // We don't know your column names, but substitute the first column (the ID) for FIRSTCOL here
        printf("<td><a href=\"listresults.php?EventID=%s\">%s</a></td>\n", $row['EventID'],$val);
     }
     print("</tr>");
  }
}
print("</table>");
?>
```

Results.php (the one I have problem with)

```
   <?
 #Get the event id from $_GET
    $int_event_id = $_GET["EventID"];
    if((int)$int_event_id)
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=clubresults', 'root', '12345678');
    #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
  $query = $pdo->query('SELECT * from results WHERE EventID ='$int_event_id' ORDER By EventID ASC');
}
    $rowset = array();

if ($query) {
  while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // Build array of rows
    $rowset[] = $row;
  }    

  // Output header first
  $headrow = $rowset[0];
  print("<table border=\"1\">\n<tr>\n");
  // Use $rowset[0] to write the table heading
  foreach ($headrow as $col => $val) {
    printf("<th>%s</th>\n", $col);
  }
  print("</tr>");

  // Then output table rows.
  // Outer loop iterates over row
  foreach ($rowset as $row) {
     print("<tr>");
     // Inner loop iterates over columns using $col => $val
     foreach ($row as $col => $val) {
        // We don't know your column names, but substitute the first column (the ID) for FIRSTCOL here
        printf("<td><a href=\"index.php?ID=%s\">%s</a></td>\n", $row['EventID'],$val);
     }
     print("</tr>");
  }
}
print("</table>");
```

I really appreciate anyone who can help me with this problem!
Thanks very much!

Last Modified with verisimilitude's Solution

Comment: I did'nt get your second question. You'd like to hide the event id and member id from view?

Comment: yes i dont want normal users to see the ID's coz they dont need to see it.

Comment: You could base 64 encode your IDs before sending them over the URL. This will make them unintelligible and the users will not be able to make them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. In your "Results.php", you need to add a where clause to your query to display the data for the particular event id only. So check my below code.

```
<?
    #Get the event id from $_GET
    $int_event_id = $_GET["EventID"];
    if((int)$int_event_id)
    {
       $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=clubresults', 'root', '12345678');
       #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
       $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

```
   $query = $pdo->query("SELECT * from results WHERE EventID ='$int_event_id' ORDER By EventID ASC");
}
```

?>

Also you are linking with "listresults.php" in "events.php", not sure if its a typo. It should be linked to "Results.php" right?

Comment: sorry er results.php is actually called "ListResults.php

Comment: Okay I have modified the original question.but now i am getting this error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\xampp\htdocs\clubresults\ListResults.php on line 53.........
Line 53 is   $query = $pdo->query('SELECT * from results WHERE EventID ='$int_event_id' ORDER By EventID ASC');

Comment: I'm sorry. Please rewrite your query as "SELECT * from results WHERE EventID ='$int_event_id' ORDER By EventID ASC" encapsulating it in double quotes rather than single quotes. Modified my answer likewise.

Comment: after modifying it, that error is gone, but I now have another 2 errors:Notice: Undefined index: EventID in C:\xampp\htdocs\clubresults\ListResults.php on line 47
 
Notice: Undefined variable: query in C:\xampp\htdocs\clubresults\ListResults.php on line 56

Comment: Remove the '}' of "if((int)$int_event_id)" and put it at the end of your code ie. at the end of the file ListResults.php.

Comment: oh ive removed the } at the end of the Select query and put it at the bottom of the file.. just before closing ?>

now Ive got 1 error left Notice: Undefined index: EventID in C:\xampp\htdocs\clubresults\ListResults.php on line 47

Comment: Line 47 is     $int_event_id = $_GET["EventID"];

Comment: :). When you are calling the listResults.php file you are sending over the Event ID. What is the name of the query parameter that you are using to send the event id ?

Comment: OH I GET WHAT YOU MEAN! YEAH IT WORKS NOW THANKS SO MUCH

Comment: Oh. one favor, could you please green tick my above answer.. Thanks :-) Was glad to fix your code/doubts.

Comment: oh erm do you know how to remove the hyperlinking in Results.php?

Comment: Sorry. Again I lost you here. Please elaborate or update your question likewise :-)

Comment: as you see in the bottom of the codes in the orginal post.. theres this code ........  printf("<td><a href=\"index.php?ID=%s\">%s</a></td>\n", $row['EventID'],$val);........... that makes like a hyperlink for every single entry... how do i remove the hyperlinking? As I want the users to be linked from events.php to results.php  but just stay at results.php

Answer (score 1):

In order to hide the EventID and MemberID columns in ListResults.php, you can simply leave them out of the select query.

So instead of querying for all columns (*):

```
SELECT * from results
```

Query for specific columns like this instead:

```
SELECT Score, Ranking FROM results
```

In your case, I suspect that you will eventually want the member name, so try something like:

```
SELECT Member.Name AS Name, Result.Score AS Score, Result.Ranking AS Ranking
FROM results
INNER JOIN members
ON results.MemberID = members.MemberID
WHERE results.EventID = '$int_event_id'
```

What this does is get the member name from the member table, where the MemberID matches with the result.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. as the names you mentioned.. from the first line Select.. Member.name, result.score and result.ranking.. as the column names in my database is EventID, MemberID, Score, Place(not ranking).. what name should i change it to?

Comment: as with the code you provided, I got this error:Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON members ON results.MemberID = members.MemberID WHERE results.EventID = '1'' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\clubresults\ListResults.php:53 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\clubresults\ListResults.php(53): PDO->query('SELECT Member.N...') #1 {main}

Comment: thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\clubresults\ListResults.php on line 53
...................where Line53 is if ($query) {

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. `INNER JOIN ON members` should be `INNER JOIN members`. I've fixed my answer to reflect that. As for the column names - you should change the SQL to the column names you actually have and use.